# Probability in Ancient Greece and Rome -- Dice vs Divination?

Tags: probability

My understanding is that probability theory is 16th or 17th century but games of chance existed 2000 years ago -- even if more complex probabilities were not understood by ancients, surely they understood that some numbers were more likely?

And would the abstract idea of randomness or probability be a concept that divination using animal guts have shared with with dice games?